# VBA Excel combining 2 folder text file

Tags: vba, excel

I found some problem with my code :

This code will insert data fine if my folder name have different name (ex 1234 with 1235), each folder have many text files. Both imported to separate sheets with correct folder name and start from column a. The problem is, if the folder name is same (1234 and 1234), It will import to same sheet(1234) but separate column (1st folder at column b and 2nd folder at column a), I want it to continue from last row at column a.

Im thinking about: I must store the MyCount value after this sub?

```
Sub InsertData(ByVal path As String)

    Dim filename As Variant
    Sheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    filename = path & Sheet & "\*.txt"
    If (filename = False) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir(filename)
    Dim MyCount As Integer
    Dim A As String
    A = 1
    MyCount = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))


    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
            Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
            Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Dim File As Variant
            File = path & Sheet & "\" & StrFile

            With ws.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & File, ws.Cells(A, 1))
            .FieldNames = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = columnFormats
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 1, 1, 9)
            .Refresh
            End With
        StrFile = Dir
        MyCount = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
        A = MyCount + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you're missing some code.  Where is StrFile defined?

Comment: StrFile before do, I'm trying to copy Important part only but I will edit it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate branch to handle a like named file.  As it stands now, your A value is not being reinitialized and the next time you go to write a differently named file on a new sheet, you will start it from the row that the last table ended on the previous sheet.

Now getting to your current problem, you are writing the new QueryTable to a space already occupied by an existing QueryTable.  When this happens, Excel shimmies the other table over.  You may have to add more than 1 row because the table may have a grand total or something at the bottom.

Add:

Debug.print ws.cells(A, 1).address

After your `A = MyCount + 1` line and see if that cell is occupied by your existing QueryTable.